# How to sort an array

Tags: arrays, sorting, go

I have problem for sorting my array in Go,
Here is my code :

```
func main() {
    fmt.Print("Masukkan Jumlah Data yang akan dimasukkan: ")
    var jumlahdata int
    fmt.Scanln(&jumlahdata)
    var DataDiagram = make([]int, jumlahdata)
    fmt.Print("Masukkan data secara berurutan dengan spasi sebagai pemisah antar angka: ")
    for i := 0; i < jumlahdata; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &DataDiagram[i])
    }
    fmt.Print("\n")
    var max int = DataDiagram[0]
    for _, value := range DataDiagram { // Menemukan nilai maximum
        if value > max {
            max = value
        }
    }
    var mem int
    Sorting(DataDiagram, jumlahdata, mem, max)
}
func Grafik(jumlahdata int, max int, DataDiagram []int) {
    for i := max; i >= 1; i-- { // membuat Data Diagram
        for j := 0; j < jumlahdata; j++ {
            if DataDiagram[j] >= i {
                fmt.Print(" | ")
            } else {
                fmt.Print("   ")
            }
        }
        fmt.Print("\n")
    }
    for i := 0; i < jumlahdata; i++ {
        fmt.Print("---")
    }
    fmt.Print("\n")
    fmt.Print(" ")
    for i := 0; i < jumlahdata; i++ {
        fmt.Print(DataDiagram[i], "  ")
    }
}
func Sorting(DataDiagram []int, jumlahdata int, mem int, max int) {
    for langkah := 0; langkah < (jumlahdata-1) ; langkah++ {
        Grafik(jumlahdata, max, DataDiagram)
        for i := 0; i < jumlahdata - (langkah-1); i++ {
            if DataDiagram[i] > DataDiagram[i + 1] {
                mem := DataDiagram[i];
                DataDiagram[i] = DataDiagram[i + 1]
                DataDiagram[i + 1] = mem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i expect is look like this:
[What I Expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSHsj.png)

But the output said otherwise, it give me error : [It give me error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVgHC.png)

Can someone give some guide how to fix this :) i just learn Go yesterday, it similiar to C, but keep giving me index out of range error

Comment: it would be easier to discuss your code if it didn't expect user input.  For the purposes of this quiestion , replace your `fmt.Scan*` calls with hard coded data.  Include also an example of the output you desire, in text form as if the program outputted it.

Comment: sorry for that, i just edited now :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your task is to sort an `int` "array" ([slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7), in go-speak), showing each step of your work as a graph.  Because you must show your work, you can't use go's built-in sorting, e.g. `sort.Ints(DataDiagram)`.

Your problems are with the `Sorting` function.

**Step 1** Your immediate crash-causing problem is that `i` eventually iterates to a number larger than upper index of `DataDiagram`.  That we fix in the commented line below.

```golang
// Step 1: fix the iterator
func Sorting(DataDiagram []int, jumlahdata int, mem int, max int) {
    for langkah := 0; langkah < (jumlahdata-1) ; langkah++ {
        Grafik(jumlahdata, max, DataDiagram)
        for i := 0; i < jumlahdata - 1; i++ { // Was: for i := 0; i < jumlahdata - (langkah-1); i++ {
            if DataDiagram[i] > DataDiagram[i + 1] {
                mem := DataDiagram[i];
                DataDiagram[i] = DataDiagram[i + 1]
                DataDiagram[i + 1] = mem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2** The code no longer crashes, but is not guaranteed to sort, because it makes only one pass through the inputs.  We need to continue looping until there's no more swapping taking place.  That problem is fixed below.  The code now [produces the expected output](https://play.golang.org/p/dZLsgpskgIn) on the playground.

```golang
// Step 2: loop until sorted
func Sorting(DataDiagram []int, jumlahdata int, mem int, max int) {
    swapped := true

    for swapped {
        Grafik(jumlahdata, max, DataDiagram)
        swapped = false
        for i := 0; i < jumlahdata - 1; i++ {
            if DataDiagram[i] > DataDiagram[i + 1] {
                mem := DataDiagram[i];
                DataDiagram[i] = DataDiagram[i + 1]
                DataDiagram[i + 1] = mem;
                swapped = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3** The above code works fine, but perhaps can use some tidying.  The end result is unchanged [on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zTma1PMESxt).

```golang
// Step 3: make it prettier
func Sorting(data []int) {

    max := data[0]

    for _, value := range data { // Menemukan nilai maximum
        if value > max {
            max = value
        }
    }

    swapped := true

    for swapped {
        Grafik(len(data), max, data)
        swapped = false
        for i := 0; i < len(data)-1; i++ {
            if data[i] > data[i+1] {
                data[i], data[i+1] = data[i+1], data[i]
                swapped = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!, was curious which was my problem. All good now, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler if you would just use
sort.Ints(ints), which you can see here:
https://goplay.space/#i9VIrDG-vL-